# How can I give each Select Option a Title value which is the same the Option via CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, meteor

In cases where the Option is too wide to fit into the Select element (and not wanting to increase the width of the entire Select element, due to "real estate" considerations), I want to add a "title" property to each element, so the user can see it in its entirety.

I can do that in the HTML by changing the options from this:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
```

...to this:

```
<option value="1" title="1">1</option>
```

...but that is tedious in the extreme. Is there a way in CSS or jQuery to mirror each Select option's value as it's title?

### UPDATE

I tried Ivanka's code (which does indeed work in the fiddle), and put it in the Meteor client startup code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
      $("#select option").each(function(i, element) {
         $(element).attr('title', $(element).val());
      });
    });
});
```

...but it has no effect...???

### UPDATE 2

I tried this, too:

```
  Template.tblScheduler.onRendered(function () {
    $("#select option").each(function(i, element) {
       $(element).attr('title', $(element).val());
    });
  });
```

...but still no joy in Mudville.

### UDPATE 3

This works:

```
  Template.tblScheduler.onRendered(function () {
    $("select option").each(function(i, element) {
       $(element).attr('title', $(element).val());
    });
  });
```

(removing the "#" so that all selects are selected, not just the selects with "select" as an ID (none of them did)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using jQuery:

```
$("select option").each(function(i, element) {
   $(element).attr('title', $(element).val());
});
```

Wrap this in `document.ready` and you are ready to go!

Here's a demo: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sw9se4d6/)

Comment: This works in the fiddle, but I guess I'm putting it in the wrong place in my Meteor .js file.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking for the correct element? `#select` looks for an element with the ID of `select`. What's your select's id?

Comment: I want all Selects; their IDs differ; I hadn't noticed the hash/pound. I'll try it without it.